# Missing icon in Windows 8 store

Tags: windows-8

I've recently uploaded my first Windows 8 Store application (hurray!)

http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/doctor-pepper-tattoo/03ed51ee-c1a4-4fb5-b388-76a2ccf10061

The only problem is that although I have specified a valid Small logo (30x30) in app manifest, it does not appear in the Windows Store. This is the file (I hope it was not converted by TinyPic)

http://i50.tinypic.com/35k9b20.png

What could be the problem? Perhaps an unsupported PNG variant? I notice that there a quite a few other apps in the Store with a missing icon (urbaneous, Volksvagen Commerial Vehicles Turkey, etc) so they could be facing a similar issue.

Thanks,
Themos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify the Store Logo in apppackage?

Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh846296.aspx) so you can read more about app images.

Answer (score 4):

Since you specified the file in app manifest it should appear when you install the application. If you had submitted the app while submission then it should have appeared on the marketplace. I do't know about the Windows 8 app procedure but since it should not much different from that of windows 7, this is only what I could comprehend. Please install and check the icons. I also hope that icon will be used when a user minimizes your tile to the smallest size on the start screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an error on Microsoft's part.  You have to make a post on:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsstore/threads

Or wait until MS updates their backend.  There is no such thing as an unsupported png, and it can be a number of issues.

This will most likely be fixed before the actual MS Windows 8 release.